# Consulta con respecto al While en PHP

Tags: php, while

Comunidad: Estoy estudiando desde cero PHP y quería entender lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$a = 1;

while($a < 1000){
      $b = 0;
      $b = $a + $b;
      echo "$b <br>";
      $a = $a + 3;
}
?>
```

Doy por entendido que mientras la variable $a sea menor a 1000 imprima de 3 en 3 números desde 1 hasta 1000. La pregunta es: ¿Por qué debo inicializar la variable $b en 0 para luego sumársela a la variable $a? Esto lo vi en un ejercicio básico.

Comment: Hola, de donde sacaste ese ejercicio por que no tiene mucho sentido, en lugar de `$b` podría imprimir `$a`, `$b` tampoco es una cadena para concatenarse, y lo que hace el while es mostrar la serie `1,4,7,10...`

Comment: Del siguiente enlace: http://tiendavirtuals.blogspot.com/2010/11/ejercicios-php-con-while.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En verdad la variable $b no esta haciendo nada importante, no es un acumulador por que se limpia nuevamente al repetir el ciclo por lo tanto, esta repitiendo el valor de $a.

Si quitas la variable $b como muestro en el codigo abajo el resultado sera el mismo

```html
<?php
$a = 1;

while($a < 1000){
      echo "$a <br>";
      $a = $a + 3;
}
?>
```

Sin la Variable $b

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado Ejecutando tu codigo (incluye variable $b)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. En conclusión: no es necesario agregar la variable $b.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo lo siguiente

```
    <?php
$a = 1;

while($a < 1000){
     $b = 0;
      $b = $a + $b;
      echo "$b <br>";
      $a = $a + 3;
}
?>
```

Ya que como lo tenías "b" siempre se iba a 0 cada vez que veía el ciclo, por lo que iba a sumar solo a+3, además si vas a hacer operaciones como buena práctica siempre es mejor inicializar las variables, aunque no tiene mucho sentido el ejercicio, considero que así es mejor práctica

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Si no inicializas b obtendrás lo siguiente

> Notice: Undefined variable: b in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 6

Así que te recomentaría que si lo hagas

Cualquier duda con gusto te ayudo

Comment: Espera, eso cambia completamente el resultado del while, en lugar de mostrar los números de 3 en 3, mostrará `1, 5, 12, 22...`

Comment: Tienes razón, supongo que perdí el enfoque del problema, ya que la pregunta principal era la linealización de b, así que yo considero que como buena práctica si debería inicializar ya que puede obtener un Notice